# IntelliJ downloading from unknown repository to support Gradle buildSrc development

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle

I'm currently working on a project in a restricted environment with an internal private repository for binaries. I need to create a custom task type which I decided to put into the `buildSrc` directory. As soon as I set up the relevant directories, IntelliJ started downloading dependencies (Groovy, Kotlin, etc.) from an unknown source. This takes a long time to complete and the IDE does this every time I ask it to refresh the Gradle build. What I've tried so far is to define a `buiild.gradle` file in the `buildSrc` directory and in it declare the internal private repository:

```
//$root/buildSrc/build.gradle

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://path/to/internal.repo'
    }
}
```

However, IntelliJ continues downloading the binaries from I don't knoow where. How do I fix this?

Comment: What do you have defined in the `repositories` section? IntelliJ IDEA uses Gradle to download dependencies, so you must configure Gradle for this. See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#declaring-repositories There is also an **offline mode** you can set in IDE explicitly for the project: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-offline.html#gradle

Comment: @Andrey Thanks. I've updated the question with a sample of what's in the `build.gradle`.

Comment: Do you use the Gradle Wrapper? Do you apply any non-built-in plugins? A [mcve] would help …

Comment: Are all the dependency downloaded from the internet? Can you give a couple examples?

Comment: @Andrey I do not know where IntelliJ is downling the dependencies from. All I can see is that, for example, it's downloading `groovy-all.pom` which takes forever. Do you know a way I can inspect this?

Comment: @Chriki I'm not sure if a minimal example would work here since it's hard to reproduce the environment in which I'm working on the code.

Comment: Yeah, maybe scratch the “reproducible” part. A minimal example would still help (and it should at least be reproducible in your environment). But without more details it’ll probably be even harder for anyone to help further.

Comment: `it's downloading groovy-all.pom which takes forever` AFAIU it should download it only once. Do you see it every time you open new Gradle project?

Comment: Yes, it does it every time I refresh the build. That's one other thing I don't understand. It's when it downloads this pom that it takes long.

Comment: Can you attach a video of this? I cannot reproduce this.